# Trying to find specific word inside string without contain method. code isn't working the way it should

Tags: c#

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sisesta suvaline tekst-->");
            string tekst1 = Console.ReadLine();
            // string tekst2 = ("ja");
            char jtaht = ('j');
            char ataht = ('a');
            int jsidOntekstis = 0;
            int asidOnTekstis = 0;
            int tekstipikkus = tekst1.Length;
            int jasidonTekstis = jsidOntekstis + asidOnTekstis;
            int jasidEiOleTekstis=1;
            for (int i = 0; i < tekstipikkus; i++)
            {
                if (tekst1[i] == jtaht)
                {
                    jsidOntekstis++;
                }
                if (tekst1[i] == ataht)
                {
                    asidOnTekstis++;
                }
            }
                // for (int k = 0; i < tekstipikkus; i++)

                    {
                        {
                        if (jasidonTekstis > jasidEiOleTekstis)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Ja on tekstis olemas");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("Ja-sid ei ole tekstis");
                        }
                    }
                        }
            Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }

        }
```

So This is my code and it isn't working the way it should. My teacher asked me to search for "ja" in text without contain method so we would think more logically. I completed all other exercises but this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is actually not a place where people DO something for you.
They help you and tell you HOW to do this. This issue contains only the wrong piece of code and question "what's wrong".

First of all, I need to tell you that the first problem is, obviously, the algorithm. 
I can't understand what is your code supposed to do because even you don't understand it.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Where to search -->");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            string pattern = "ja"; // Probably, it is better to get it from Console as well      

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (text[i+j] == pattern[j] && j == pattern.Length - 1)
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    if (text[i+j] != pattern[j]) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the (not a best) code which searches for the pattern in the text without Contains method. It iterates through the text string - and if it meets the first character of pattern string - it goes further comparing characters one by one in a row. If the inner loop iterated till the end then it means that text string contains pattern string and outputs it's position. If in any moment characters are not equal then the inner loop breaks and continues the main loop.

Research it and understand it. Then you can solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry as i don't understand the meaning of stackoverflow although i just want to learn and feed my passion of programming! Thank for your answer and now i can understand logic of finding string inside string! I try to ask better questions from here.

Comment: What happens if the word isn't found?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This code is not a solution but just a sample.
Here, nothing would happen (empty output) if word isn't found. You can easily add a bool flag and output "Not found" in the end if necessary.